# Accessing scoped enums declared outside classes

Tags: c++, enums, header-files

Here is my current setup:

```
// test.h
enum class test_t {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR};

// test.cpp
#include "test.h"

// main.cpp
#include "test.h"
test_t thing = test_t::ONE;
```

However, I'm getting `error: expected a class or namespace` when trying to create the enum object in `main.cpp`. I declared the scoped enum in the header because both `test.cpp` and `main.cpp` need access to it eventually.

Is there something off with my current set up? I'm very new to C++ so it's possible I'm overlooking something dead simple.

Comment: The code looks fine. You need C++11 support for this. But what is the point of the function here? It isn't related to the problem. See [this working example](http://ideone.com/90SBjv).

Comment: Are you sure your compiler supports C++11?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm starting to wonder if my compiler is the issue then... I'm running OSX and using `g++` to compile.

Comment: @user83643 Are you sure that there is no macro with name test_t or some typedef that hides your definition of the enumeration?

Comment: Figured out what the issue was. I needed to supply `-std=c++11` to `g++` to compile with c++11 features. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @user83643 It depends on your version of g++, but in any case you need to use the flag `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` in older versions.)

Answer (score 2):

This type of `enum` declaration needs C++11 to compile.

I needed to add the `-std=c++11` flag to g++ when compiling to make sure the support was there.